# add values of 2 Dropdown list and textfield together display result in another textfield in yii

Tags: ajax, drop-down-menu, yii

I have two dropDownlists and a textfield. I want to add their values together and display the results in another textfield using Yii.
In the _form i have this.

```
      <tr>
    <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'typeofpaper'); ?></td>
    <td><?php $data = CHtml::listData(PaperType::model()->findAll(),'id','title'); 
              if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))
              {
                  $sel = $_REQUEST['id'];
              } else {
                  $sel =''; 
              }
            echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'typeofpaper', $data, array('prompt'=>'Type of Paper','options'=>array($sel=>array('selected'=>true)))); 

        ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'typeofpaper'); ?></td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'deadline'); ?></td>

    <td><?php   echo $form->dropDownList($model,'deadline',

      array('3hrs'=> '3 hrs', '6hrs'=>'6 hrs', '12hrs'=>'12 hrs', '24hrs'=>'1 day', '48hrs'=>'2 days', '72hrs'=>'3 days',
            '96hrs'=>'4 days', '120hrs'=>'5 days', '144hrs'=>'6 days', '168hrs'=>'7 days', '172hrs'=>'8 days', '196hrs'=>'9 days',
            '220hrs'=>'10 days', '244hrs'=>'11 days', '268hrs'=>'12 days', '292hrs'=>'13 days', '316hrs'=>'14 days', '340hrs'=>'15 days'),array('empty' => 'Select Urgency Level')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'deadline'); ?> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'nopages'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->textField($model,'nopages'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'nopages'); ?></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and follow these guidelines

According to yii`public string dropDownList(CModel $model, string $attribute, array $data, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))` for dropdowns.

since $data and let say $deadlineData = array('3hrs'=>'3 hrs','6hrs'=>'6 hrs'...) are arrays and represent the list options(value=>display), you can use array_merge($data,$deadlineData) to combine the two arrays and use a foreach to loop through and get the combined results.You can then go ahead and output the result in a text field